# How would I focus on a input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to focus on a input using jQuery. I can easily do this by using the id of the input tag, however this is set to the id from a database field, and is ordered in a different way. This makes this not work as well as i want when using to focus on. What I want to be able to do is use the HTML5 data attribute to focus onto so the following would work:

`<input class="navigable" type="text" data-id="1" ID="123" data-number="1" maxsize="1">` I want to be able to focus on this using jQuery. Currently I have:

```
$('.navigable').keyup(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var next = $('#txt'+(self.data('number')+1));
    if(next.length > 0 && self.val().length == self.attr('size')) {
    next.focus();
}
```

My HTML tag has to be like this:

```
<input type="text" class="navigable" id="txt1" data-number="1" maxsize="1">
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `maxsize` attribute do?

Answer (score 1):

You have typo in your code. You forgot to close if condition `}`. And `self.attr('size')` will return undefined. Because you dont have any attribute named size in your input. So replace `self.attr('size')` with `self.data('number')`.

Try this:

```
$('.navigable').keyup(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var next = $('#txt'+(self.data('number')+1));
    console.log(next);
    if(next.length > 0 && self.val().length == self.data('number')) {
    next.focus();
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/Vf3Qp/)**

Comment: How did you know that `self.val().length` should be compared to `self.data('number')`?.

Comment: @RahilWazir: OP is trying to compare with size of the input value which is nothing but `self.data('number')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

[Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('input.navigable[data-number="1"]').focus();
```

---

```
$('.navigable').keyup(function () {
    var self = $(this);
    var next = $('input.navigable[data-number="' + (self.data('number')+1) + '"]');
    if (next.length > 0 && self.val().length == self.data('number')) {
        next.focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: This will move focus to next element even if previous inputs are empty. Hope OP wants to move focus to next element with condition to check data-number should be equal to size of input value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `autofocus` attribute on your input element, which is plain HTML5.

```
$('input.navigable[data-number="' + num +'"]').prop('autofocus', true);
```